# How can I estimation the file size of an image using its width and height?

Tags: php, file, resize, getimagesize

I have recently written an image resizing program using php, which works by downloading images off another server, resizing them and saving them to our own.

The bad news is that my Hosting account only allows a php memory limit of 64M, and this is just not set up to resize the HUUUUGE file sizes that my client is uploading (3 - 4mb). It spits out a fatal error if it meets these images and breaks the script.

Even though I have notified said client of this drawback, said client continues to upload large images and script keeps breaking.

I can obtain the width and the height of the image before downloading it using `getimagesize()`, and if I could use this info to work out the total file size I could break out before the image resizer gets going and suppliment the image with a nice "no image available" alternative.

**How can I make an accurate estimation of an images file size using its width and height, assuming it has a bit depth of 24?**

Answer (score 3):

An image in memory always weights the same weight compressed in JPEG or GIF or BMP. It's called a BIT-MAP. So, if you want to calculate the size of an image in memory, take the width, the height and the bit size to get the bit weight, divide by 8 and you get the bytesite.

```
$ByteSize = Width*Heigh*(24/8)
```

Note that it is possible to get more weight from an image in some parts such as a paletized image, it will have to store the image color palette in memory but most of the time this should weight less than a bitmap.

Comment: but there is no way to get width & height in php without an uploaded file! getimagesize() works with an already uploaded file

Comment: Note that there are some exceptions to this rule.  For example, ImageMagick, using libjpeg, can scale non-progressive JPEG images without loading the entire image into memory; this is how Wikipedia is able to rescale some [ridiculously large images](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Georgetown_PowerPlant_interior_pano.jpg) on what aren't really particularly beefy servers.  In principle, there's no reason why similar techniques couldn't be used for other image formats, if someone just wrote the software to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A multiplication. 
Just multiply height by width by 3. 
and throw in some spare memory to process all these bytes. say, twice the image size.

It has nothing to do with *file size* though.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I had the calculation already but was getting it confused with filesize - cheers

Answer (score 0):

before the upload on the server you can't with php,
but you can use javascript!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File

will work in conjunction of  and will instantly provide the filesize using

```
fileInput.files[0].fileSize
```

read these:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/multiple-file-input-in-firefox-3-6/

hope this helps!

Comment: aaaah, but it would have been so simple! unfortunately, my site interacts with an external software kit where all the files are uploaded, I have absolutely no control over what goes on here. :(

Comment: @BenAzouelos the files are already uploaded and available locally? or you get them by $_FILES ?

Comment: I have an XML feed which is downloaded and extracted, this provides the location of each image, however they are not on my server. I then Loop through and use an image resize script on each URL and save to my server. Thanks to the responses here, I have already solved my problem with a technique to work out the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

The size will always depend on the format. When compressing images, the size of the image itself won't have any effect on the filesize. The only way that you can get a good readout of the filesize is if you use a Bitmap (or simmilar) format.

Example, A JPEG could be 10MB in size, and then when rotated only 1 MB in size because of how the compression works.